# How to manage multiple NSWindows in a dictionary

Tags: swift, macos

### What I'm trying to do:

I'm currently developing a Command-Line-Tool that creates a blurred window for each desktop space available. I save these windows in a dictionary where the `spaceIdentifier` is the `key`and the `NSWindow` is the `value`.
In order to keep the windows in sync with the spaces I periodically check if there are new spaces or if spaces are closed.

### My Code:

```
import AppKit
import Foundation

func createBlurWindow(screen: NSScreen?, contentRect: NSRect, brightness: Int) -> NSWindow
{
    # irrelevant code that creates a blurred window
}

class AppController: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate
{
    var spaceWindowList: [NSNumber: NSWindow] = [:]

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        self.manageWindows()
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.manageWindows), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func manageWindows()
    {
        // create windows
        for scr in NSScreen.screens {
            let scrHeight = scr.frame.height
            let scrWidth = scr.frame.width
            let windowHeight = CGFloat(22)
            let size = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrHeight-windowHeight, width: scrWidth, height: windowHeight)

            let currentScreenSpaces = WindowHelper.getSpacesforScreen(scr)
            for space in currentScreenSpaces!
            {
                if self.spaceWindowList[space] == nil
                {
                    let w = createBlurWindow(screen: scr, contentRect: size, brightness: 9)
                    let windowID = NSNumber.init(value: w.windowNumber)

                    // @TODO this may fail if the space was created just now -> fix this by waiting some time
                    WindowHelper.moveWindow(windowID, toSpace: space)

                    self.spaceWindowList[space] = w

                    // debuginfo
                    let displayNr = scr.deviceDescription[NSDeviceDescriptionKey("NSScreenNumber")]!
                    print(getTime(), " Display:", displayNr, " added Window(", windowID , ") for Space: ", space, separator: "")
                }
            }
        }

        let currentSpaces = WindowHelper.getAllSpaces()
        for (space, window) in self.spaceWindowList
        {
            // destroy window if space was closed
            if !(currentSpaces?.contains(space))!
            {
                window.close()
                //self.spaceWindowList.removeValue(forKey: space)

                // debuginfo
                print(getTime(), "Destroyed window of closed Space:", space)
            }
        }
    }
}


let app = NSApplication.shared
let controller = AppController()
app.delegate = controller
app.run()
```

The complete source can be found [here](https://github.com/kinglouie/BlurWindow)

#### My Problem:

When detecting that a space was closed I try to programatically close the corresponding NSWindow, however the next time `manageWindows()` is called the application segfaults on this loop: `for (space, window) in self.spaceWindowList`. To debug I activated zombieobjects and got the following errormessage `-[NSWindow retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x101241150`
I don't understand why there is still a pointer to my window the next time `spaceWindowList` is iterated. I also tried to `nil` the dictionary entry with `self.spaceWindowList.removeValue(forKey: space)` but that also lead to a segfault.

I'm fairly new to swift and macdev in general so I'm not that confident with memory management in swift. 
I would really appreciate if someone could tell me the best way to safely close windows organized in some kind of dictionary/map/whatever.

#### PS:

If you are wondering why I don't use `.canJoinAllSpaces` instead of creating the window for each space: When using `.canJoinAllSpaces` you can see the blurred NSEffectView flickering on a space change if the spaces have different desktop images. The only way to circumvent this is to create individual windows for each space.

Comment: Lack of relevant tags...  "I'm currently developing a cli that creates a blurred window for each desktop space available."  I don't even know what a 'cli' is.

Comment: @ElTomato CLI - command line interface. Almost every developer uses such tools once in a while.

Comment: @Cristik, are you really sure about that? Do you really implement the NSApplicationDelegate for a command line program? Maybe cli is short for client?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes I'm sure that CLI stands for `Command Line Interface`.

Comment: Ok if you say so. But it was not written with capital letters like an acronym and also CLI is an interface where you can give commands to a program, its not the program. That's called a CLT command-line-tool in Xcode. But hey, maybe the OP is writing a new CLI for OS X...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson instead of arguing on acronyms maybe we should try to help the OP. So far none of the comments posted here are constructive (mines included).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson pardon my ignorance, you're right, what I meant is a CLT, but as Cristik already pointed out, this discussion doesn't help with my issue :). If it helps the complete source can be found [here](https://github.com/kinglouie/BlurWindow). Steps to reproduce: 1. Run, 2. Create new Space, 3. Wait 5 seconds, 4. Close a space